# doubly linked list empty situation

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

In my lecture noes its given that if doubly linked list is empty then

```
header.next==tail;
```

Or

```
tail.prev==header;
```

But I feel like this is the case when there's exactly two nodes. Shouldn't the empty case be 
`head==null`.
I don't know if I am correct.I am sill new to this subject.Can someone please clarify this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways to store a double linked-list:

- Let `head` and `tail` refer to actual nodes in the tree.

  ```
  head variable       tail variable
    |                   |
    V                   V
  first -> second -> third -> null
  ```

  In this case, you are correct - `head` will be `null`.
- Let `head` and `tail` be special nodes (called ["sentinel nodes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), as pointed out in the other answer) which don't actually contain any data and point to the first and last nodes in the list through `next` and `prev` respectively.

  ```
  head variable                       tail variable
    |                                   |
    V                                   V
  head -> first -> second -> third -> tail -> null
  node                                node
  ```

  In this case, `header.next == tail` will mean the list is empty.

  One might use this approach instead of the above one to simplify the implementation a bit and make the code a bit faster - there's no need to make special provision for removing or inserting the first or last nodes.

Comment: Thanks.We were not taught about sentinels.In the note its given that ""Doubly linked list has a reference , **header** that point to the first node in the sequence and a reference,**tail**,that points at the last end of the sequence".In that context I think though the code for sentinel approach is given since head and tail refer to actual nodes in the tree, the correct one would be `head==null`

Comment: Yes, I'd agree with you about that phrasing implying `head==null` indicates an empty list, but it could also be that the phrasing is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This doubly-linked list is using both head and tail [sentinel nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384358/how-does-a-sentinel-node-offer-benefits-over-null). These are nodes that don't actually contain elements of the list, but help to make certain algorithms slightly nicer by making the head and tail cases work more like the middle of the list.

If the list weren't using sentinels, then the empty case would be `head==null`, and the two-element case would have `header.next==tail` and `tail.prev==header`.