# How to properly use sentinel nodes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, sentinel

There will be multiple (closely) related questions instead of a single one. For our comfort, I will number them accordingly.

Based on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384358/how-does-a-sentinel-node-offer-benefits-over-null) and lectures, I think I already understand the idea behind sentinel nodes and their usage in linked lists. However, a few things are still not clear to me even after reading these materials.

I was given a basic implementation of a doubly linked list (it stores only int values) and the task is to change the implementation so it uses a sentinel node like this:

[Illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7aT8.jpg) (not allowed to embed images yet, sorry)

### Question 1

I am assuming that the `head` variable of the list will point to the first real node (the one after sentinel node) and the `tail` variable will simply point to the last node. Am I correct or should the `head` point to the sentinel node? I am asking for a best-practice or the most standard approach here.

### Question 2

I understand that when searching for a value in the list, I no longer have to check for nullptr since I am using a sentinel node. Since the list basically formed a circle thanks to the sentinel node, I have to terminate it after iterating through the whole list and reaching it. Can I do it by putting the value I am looking for in the sentinel node and use it as a sentinel value of sorts and then check if the result is returned from the sentinel node when the loop ends? Some sources claim that sentinel nodes should not store any values at all. Is my approach correct/reasonably effective?

### Question 3

When simply iterating and not searching for a particular value (e.g. counting nodes, outputting the whole list into the console), do I have to check for the sentinel node the same way as I would for a nullptr (to terminate the iterating loop) or is there a different or smarter way of doing this?

Comment: just out of curiosity, in your image, why doesn't the last node of the list have a next ptr to the sentinel ?

Comment: That's a good question, I didn't even notice (I am not the creator of it). I'd automatically assume that "next" for the last element would be the sentinel node and "prev" of the sentinel node would be the last element. So it would form a circle.

Comment: Okay, then in that case this is not just a doubly linked list, but introduction of the sentinel would make this a modified circular doubly linked list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer 1

Yes this is a valid position for the sentinelnode to take. `head` and `tail` can point to the actual beginning and end of the data. But your `add` and `delete` functions will need to be aware of the aberrations caused at the list boundaries by virtue of the sentinel node

## Answer 2

Yes this is a valid search strategy and is infact called the [Elephant in Cairo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_Cairo) technique

## Answer 3

Yes, the purpose of the sentinel node is to let you know that it is the sentinel node. You could just maintain a constant pointer (or whatever your lang of choice supports) to this sentinel node to check if you are at the sentinel node or just stick a flag in the node.

Comment: Ad Answer 3 - add a flag to the general node struct/class such as `isSentinel` and check just for that?

Comment: honestly I'd prefer a pointer approach as it makes fewer assumptions, but yes, if that isn't possible then a flag like what you suggested would work where a sentinel node is s special class of regular nodes.

Comment: The pointer approach seems to be easier in my case, thank you. Is it even possible to use a single sentinel node effectively without looping the list? I don't think so but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If your sentinel node sits at the beginning/end of a list its purpose is to notify you that when you pass it you have successfully "looped" around the list once. I would say the sentinel has most effectively served its purpose then, what did you have in mind ?

Comment: Whether it is even possible to have a single sentinel node at the beginning/end of a list and keep the list linear (not looped through the node - e.g. the last element does not point to the sentinel node at the beginning). I think this is impossible but I've seen way too much contradicting stuff about sentinel nodes already.

Comment: I mean technically you could, but the effectiveness of your sentinel would be greatly diminished and you have 2 types of endgames to check for. If you sentinel will sit at the beginning but not at the end, then you have to check for `null` at the end, and the reverse if the sentinel sits at the end. Ideally the sentinel strategy in this context is a drop in replacement for checking for null,  so I would not recommend that

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Thank you, your answer and this comment clarifies it for me. Marking as accepted.