# How to delete the node in double-linked-list by C programming? I made it but it returns segmentation error. I don't know which part is wrong

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
struct someEvent
{
    int shouldRemove;
    struct someEvent *prev;
    struct someEvent *next;
} * someEvent;

struct someEvent *someEventQueue = NULL;
```

This part is the code of structure of double-linked-list.

```
struct someEvent **curr = &someEventQueue; 
            if ((*curr) == NULL)
            {
                someEventQueue = &someEvent[0];
                someEventQueue->next = NULL;
                someEventQueue->prev = NULL;
            }
            else
            {

                while ((*curr)->next != NULL)
                {
                    curr = &(*curr)->next;
                }
                struct someEvent *tmp = (struct someEvent *)malloc(sizeof(struct someEvent));
                tmp = &someEvent[0];
                tmp->next = NULL;
                (*curr)->next = tmp;
                tmp->prev = (*curr);
            }
```

This part is inserting node to double-linked-list.

```
struct someEvent **curr5 = &someEventQueue;
            if ((*curr5) != NULL)
            {
                while ((*curr5) != NULL)
                {
                    if ((*curr5)->shouldRemove == 1)
                    {
                        if ((*curr5)->prev == NULL && (*curr5)->next == NULL)
                        {
                            (*curr5) = NULL;
                        }
                        else if ((*curr5)->prev != NULL)
                        {
                            (*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;
                            if ((*curr5)->next != NULL)
                            {
                                (*curr5)->next->prev = (*curr5)->prev;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            (*curr5) = (*curr5)->next;
                            if ((*curr5) != NULL)
                            {
                                (*curr5)->prev = NULL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    curr5 = &(*curr5)->next;
                }
            }
```

This part is deleting node. Before doing this, I checked all node which must be deleted and marked by using shouldRemove. If shouldRemove is 1, then this node sholud be deleted. I think there is no problem but when I debug this code, it returns segmentation error in `while ((*curr5) != NULL)`(this code is the 4th line of deleting node part.) I really tried hard to solve this problem but I think I can't solve this problem.. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Read [thist article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I am struggling to understand in what scope this line exists struct someEvent *someEventQueue = NULL;

Comment: @Gliad `struct someEvent *someEventQueue = NULL;` this line is glabal variance. inserting part and deleting part code is in main function.

Comment: Please read about [managing a doubly-linked list with a sentinel node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049478/sentinel-approach-with-doubly-linked-list), it makes life so much easier.