# Embedding sentinel node within a container object. Is this a good implementation strategy for a node based container?

Tags: c++

For example, `std::list`'s implementation of libstdc++ and libc++ embeds the sentinel node within the `std::list` object. While the msvc's implementation heap-allocates the sentinel node. The consequences are...
'embedding' case

1. Some constructor's are noexcept qualified and fast, because they can omit one heap allocation. Especially, the move constructor can be noexcept qualified, this can be a huge positive performance impact if they are used as the element type of `std::vector`-like container.
2. They can't be trivially-relocatble. So, some performance benefits may disappear.
3. Fancy pointer support is limited. Some time it would work, otherwise
   would cause undefined behavior.

So, there are pros and cons. Is this strategy worth to pursue?

Comment: This of course depends on there actually being a sentinel node. Which is not always needed. Or take the old [Amiga `List` structure](https://wiki.amigaos.net/wiki/Exec_Lists_and_Queues#List_Structure), where the actual `List` structure itself acted as a sentinel.

Comment: Since we don't have a trait for "trivially relocatable" (yet?), #2 doesn't seem to be an issue. I don't understand #3, can you elaborate?

Comment: `embedding` case.. do you mean running on embedded? Then std::list is probably not what you want anyway. (It is already full of dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, trivially-relocatable trait may be included in the standard near future and there are already some (third party)libraries which takes advantage of trivial-relocatability. Some fancy pointer requires that the address must be within a certain range.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, "do you mean running on embedded?" sorry no. I meant that there is a implementation strategy of node based container, so that the sentinel node is constructed within the container object(to avoid heap allocation for the sentinel node).

Comment: Sure you can do that, might even safe a few bytes by making the sentinel node static  (so all instances of a list share the same sentinel).  Have you read this : [how does a sentinal node differ from nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384358/how-does-a-sentinel-node-offer-benefits-over-null)